# how can i set the value of an array to be the name of a variable i want to recall by an command (in java)?

Tags: java, arrays

**INTRODUCTION:**

I'm making a small chess game where I use pictures to represent all the pieces, all my pieces are controlled by an function that draws them on the bord. the position of all the pieces is recorded in an array, but now I want to use what is recorded in the array to select what image is needed on what tile on the board, so far I have got a 99% working script with only one problem in it.

**MAIN PROBLEM:**

java does not except what is in my array to select the right picture I loaded earlier:

```
void tekenstukken(){
  for(int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++){

      image(schaakstukken[y][x], x*blokgroote, y*blokgroote, blokgroote, blokgroote);
      // -------- blokgroote is dutch for blocksize --------
} } }
```

in this code the only thing that does not work is `schaakstukken[y][x]` this holds the names of the `IPmage` variables i made earlier:

```
String[][] schaakstukken = new String[][]{      //schaakstukken means chesspieces in dutch
  {"Tb","Hb","Rb","Qb","Kb","Rb","Hb","Tb"},    //Tb is my name for the Tower on the Black side, the other names are simulair
  {"Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb"},
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  {"Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw"},
  {"Tw","Hw","Rw","Qw","Kw","Rw","Hw","Tw"}
};
```

here is my **ENTIRE CODE:**

```
String[][] schaakstukken = new String[][]{
  {"Tb","Hb","Rb","Qb","Kb","Rb","Hb","Tb"},
  {"Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb","Pb"},
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  { "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" , "" },
  {"Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw","Pw"},
  {"Tw","Hw","Rw","Qw","Kw","Rw","Hw","Tw"}
};
int breedte = 800;
int hoogte = breedte;
int blokgroote = breedte/8;
int blokkleur1 = #ffffff;
int blokkleur2 = #999999;
PImage Tb;
PImage Hb;
PImage Rb;
PImage Qb;
PImage Kb;
PImage Pb;
PImage Tw;
PImage Hw;
PImage Rw;
PImage Qw;
PImage Kw;
PImage Pw;


void setup(){
  size(breedte, hoogte);
  noStroke();
  Tb = loadImage("Tb.png");
  Hb = loadImage("Hb.png");
  Rb = loadImage("Rb.png");
  Qb = loadImage("Qb.png");
  Kb = loadImage("Kb.png");
  Pb = loadImage("Pb.png");
  Tw = loadImage("Tw.png");
  Hw = loadImage("Hw.png");
  Rw = loadImage("Rw.png");
  Qw = loadImage("Qw.png");
  Kw = loadImage("Kw.png");
  Pw = loadImage("Pw.png");      
  tekenbord();
  tekenstukken();      
}

void draw(){

}

void tekenbord(){
  for(int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++){
      if((x+y)%2 == 0){
        fill(blokkleur1);
      }else{
        fill(blokkleur2);
      }
      rect(x*blokgroote, y*blokgroote, blokgroote, blokgroote);
} } } 

void tekenstukken(){
  for(int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++){    
      image(schaakstukken[y][x], x*blokgroote, y*blokgroote, blokgroote, blokgroote);    
} } }
```

When I disable `tekenstukken()` my code runs fine and draws an empty chessboard. if i replace `schaakstukken[y][x]` by `Tb` or one of the other names I get a chessboard filled with 1 kind of chess piece.

NOTE: My code is not finished yet I will later add an fuction that changes the array that controls the chess pieces according to what the player changes on the board.

Comment: What is `image()` because that's where the problem seems to lie.

Comment: Do not store strings in the array, store `PImage`s: `PImage[][] schaakstukken`. That lets you say `{Tb,Hb,Rb,Qb,Kb,Rb,Hb,Tb}` - you just need to fill you array after you load your images.

Comment: In any case, later on you'll find that you need to store much more for a square than the picture of piece that's occupying it.

Comment: i would agree with @Arkadiy, use the actual instance in array instead of the instance name, you dont need reflection and it is faster and more flexible

Comment: One small performance tip regarding the board array: it's easier and faster to use a one dimensional array for the board that has 12x10 or more fields. Fill extra fields with a _not allowed_ marker. Look at this for an example: http://www.trinimon.de/Chess/ChessGame/Develop/chess10src.htm

Comment: I used the solution provided by @Arkadiy and my code now works :D , thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is really necessary for writing a chess program ;) but you could achieve this by using [Java's Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html):

```
Class chessClass = ChessClass.class;
Field[] fields= chessClass.getFields();

for (Field f : fields) {
    // ... assign name to array: array[...] = f.getName();
}
```

For more check [ORACLEs Java Reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score 0):

@Arkadiy provided me with a solution for my problem:

> Do not store strings in the array, store `PImages:`  `PImage[][] schaakstukken`. That lets you say `{Tb,Hb,Rb,Qb,Kb,Rb,Hb,Tb}` - you just need to fill you array after you load your images.

THANKS FOR THE HELP AND SUPPORT!

here is my working code:

```
int breedte = 800;
int hoogte = breedte;
int blokgroote = breedte/8;
int blokkleur1 = #ffffff;
int blokkleur2 = #999999;
PImage Tb;
PImage Hb;
PImage Rb;
PImage Qb;
PImage Kb;
PImage Pb;
PImage Tw;
PImage Hw;
PImage Rw;
PImage Qw;
PImage Kw;
PImage Pw;
PImage E;
PImage[][] schaakstukken;

void setup(){
  size(breedte, hoogte);
  noStroke();
  Tb = loadImage("Tb.png");
  Hb = loadImage("Hb.png");
  Rb = loadImage("Rb.png");
  Qb = loadImage("Qb.png");
  Kb = loadImage("Kb.png");
  Pb = loadImage("Pb.png");
  Tw = loadImage("Tw.png");
  Hw = loadImage("Hw.png");
  Rw = loadImage("Rw.png");
  Qw = loadImage("Qw.png");
  Kw = loadImage("Kw.png");
  Pw = loadImage("Pw.png");
  E  = loadImage("E.png");
  schaakstukken = new PImage[][]{
  {Tb,Hb,Rb,Qb,Kb,Rb,Hb,Tb},
  {Pb,Pb,Pb,Pb,Pb,Pb,Pb,Pb},
  {E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E },
  {E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E },
  {E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E },
  {E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E ,E },
  {Pw,Pw,Pw,Pw,Pw,Pw,Pw,Pw},
  {Tw,Hw,Rw,Qw,Kw,Rw,Hw,Tw}};            
  tekenbord();
  tekenstukken();      
}

void draw(){
}    

void tekenbord(){
  for(int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++){
      if((x+y)%2 == 0){
        fill(blokkleur1);
      }else{
        fill(blokkleur2);
      }
      rect(x*blokgroote, y*blokgroote, blokgroote, blokgroote);
} } } 

void tekenstukken(){
  PImage schaakstuk;
  for(int x = 0 ; x < 8 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0 ; y < 8 ; y++){    
      image(schaakstukken[y][x], x*blokgroote, y*blokgroote, blokgroote, blokgroote);    
} } }
```